# ELF32 binary, little endian or not?

Tags: stack, printf, elf

I know that `printf(%08x)` shows 4 octets of the stack (`410484e4` for instance). Let's say that this value correspond to the begining of a char array (called tab), so what would be the value of `tab[0]`, would it be `08` ('A' converted in ASCII) or `e4` (ä) ?

Thank you

p.s: the executable I'm working on is an ELF 32 binary

Comment: "ELF is flexible and extensible by design, and it is not bound to any particular processor or architecture. This has allowed it to be adopted by many different operating systems on many different platforms."  Which platform/OS are you using?